# Send-MailMessage - Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: powershell, smtp

I work on a server on Windows Server 2016.
My aim is to send a mail using PowerShell, I wrote the script below.

```
Send-MailMessage -From "john.doe@mydomaine.com" -To "john.doe@mydomaine.com" -Subject "votre objet" -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -Body "Blablabla" -Credential "john.doe@mydomaine.com" -Port "587" -UseSsl
```

This script works fine when I execute it on my PC, the mail is sent. So my script is OK.

When I execute it on the server I have this error "Unable to connect to the remote server". When I ping the smtp.office365.com, it is OK.

Does anyone have a idea about what is the problem?

Here the complete error:

```
Send-MailMessage : Impossible de se connecter au serveur distant
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Send-MailMessage -From "john.doe@mydomaine.com" -To "john.doe@myd ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Comment: Try `telnet smtp.office365.com 587` - it's probably blocked (you might need to install telnet client to your server if you don't have it)

Comment: I already have telnet installed on the server. I tried your command line and obtain : `"Connexion à smtp.office365.com...Impossible d’ouvrir une connexion à l’hôte, sur le port 587: Échec lors de la connexion"` (With the traduction : `Unable to open a connection on the host`)

Comment: So that confirms that firewall is blocking access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. I am now using port 25 and it works, the mail is correctly sent from the server.

Answer (score 1):

**I was getting this error** when **using** `smtp.live.com` as the SMTP server (sending an email to my hotmail address, from my hotmail address). Was working until around Jan 2022.

After **changing it to** `smtp.office365.com` **emails are working** again.

Answer (score -1):

step 1:
include both $SMTPPort:25 AND $SMTPPort:587

Step2:You may have to allow access to "less secure apps" in your google account settings
Go to https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and set it to "On" and try again

Comment: how do you add the 2nd port? do you put two lines?

Answer (score -2):

#### Get the user credentails

```
$username = "xxx@gmail.com"
$password = "" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

#### Create hash for email

```
$email = @{
  from = $username
  to = "xxx@gmail.com"
  subject = "Hello"
  smtpserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
  body = "hi"
  credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password
  Port = "587" 
  UseSsl = $true
}

Send-MailMessage @email
```