# Launch a powershell function in a new window from inside a windows service

Tags: powershell

I have the following function:

```
Function Email{
param ($to, $Subject, $Body, $Attachment)
$Outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = $To
$Mail.Subject = $Subject
$Mail.Body = $Body
$Mail.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
$Mail.Send()
}
```

It works perfectly in tests in the ISE, but from within another script running as a service it fails. So within that parent script I am trying to launch it in a new powershell instance to see if it will run there, but it does not seem to. Within the parent script I have:

```
    Import-Module C:\...\Email.ps1
    $to = Myemail
    $Subject = "Test"
    $Result = $Result[0].FullName 
    $Body = (-join("'",$Result,"'"))
    write-host $to $Subject $Body $Result #test to make sure params are visible, test successful

    $Command = Email $to $Subject $Body $Result

    Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-WindowStyle Maximized -command invoke-command -scriptblock {$command} -argumentlist $to $Subject $Body $Result"
```

However it still appears to be non-functional within the service. Is this because of an error on my part?

Comment: A service cannot interface with desktop for security reasons; this is by design since Win Vista. Why use Outlook when there's [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7)?

Comment: @vonPryz Because I cannot get past the "cannot connect to remote server" error

Comment: Pass proper parameters to Send-MailMessage and it sure can. What those are, depends on your network setup. SMTP server, authentication, port number, maybe firewall config. See [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52271686) question. If you get errors, add the command and error to the question body.

Comment: I have my code up in another question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296033/use-powershell-to-send-an-email-in-outlook-without-locking-up-if-outlook-is-alre?noredirect=1#comment106659047_60296033

Comment: `$Command = Email $to $Subject $Body $Result` doesn't define a command for _later invocation_, it _instantly calls_ function `Email` and stores whatever it outputs in `$Command`. Even if you defined it as a script block (`$Command = `{ ... }`), it wouldn't see the referenced variables if run in a child process run by `Start-Process` - unless added a `param(...)` block defining inside the script block that defines these variables as _parameters_ received via the `-ArgumentList` arguments.